Jeep cherokee oil leak
Oil is leaking around/near transmission and transfer case. Does not leak when idling in park. Only leaks in drive. It is also AWD.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question? It seems you've already located where the leak is. What is the year/engine of your Cherokee?
